# How to use tryCatch in R to set value to 0?

Tags: r

I'm not very experienced with R and I'm trying to do some error handling.
Heres my code:

```
tryCatch(Retest_rate <- GetReTestRate(Data))
  error = function(e){
    Retest_rate <- 0
    return(Retest_rate)
  }
```

I just want Retest_rate to be zero if an error occurs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try -

```
Retest_rate <- tryCatch(GetReTestRate(Data),error = function(e) 0)
```

As an example -

```
a <- 2
Retest_rate <- tryCatch(a * 2,error = function(e) 0)
Retest_rate
#[1] 4


a <- 'a'
Retest_rate <- tryCatch(a * 2,error = function(e) 0)
Retest_rate
#[1] 0
```